# Greatest common divisor of $(a^n+1,b^n+1)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples

Let $(a,b)$ be a pair of coprime positive integers with $a$ being even. Are these conditions sufficient to prove that there exist infinitely many positive integers $n,$ such that $(a^n+1,b^n+1)=1$ ?

Comment: "Sufficient to prove that" is an interesting formulation :) If it is taken literally, then I am clueless about the answer since nobody has been able to prove this. In other words, this is a well known conjecture. However, using the work of Corvaja and Zannier based on Schmidt's Subspace theorem, one can at least prove the sub-exponential upper bound $\exp(\varepsilon n)$ on this gcd, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, and infinitely many $n$. (Indeed all large enough $n$ if additionally $a$ and $b$ are multiplicatively independent.)

Comment: If you can prove there is one n, you should be able to prove there are infinitely many.  Gerhard "Start With A Simpler Case" Paseman,  2019.07.31.

Comment: Is it at least true that there are infinitely many values of $n$ with $(2^n+1,3^n+1)=1$?

Comment: Thank you very much for enlightening me. I was almost sure that it is a famous conjecture, but I couldn't find any papers about it.

Comment: Is it known that for any set $P$ of primes of positive relative density ($|P\cap[1,x]\gg x/\log x$) there are infinitely many exponents $n$ such that $b^n+1$ is divisible only by the primes from $P$? Choosing $P$ to be the set of all primes $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$ such that $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, for every such $n$ we will have $(a^n+1,b^n+1)=1$ since $a^n+1$ is not divisible by primes $p\in P$ in view of $a^n\equiv -1\pmod p$.

Comment: @Seva: A typical integer will have a prime factor $p \notin P$, if the density of $P$ is smaller than $1$. (By an upper bound sieve, the set of positive integers composed entirely of primes from $P$ has natural asymptotic density zero.)

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov: sure; and yet, atypical integers of the form $b^n+1$ can exist.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that this sort of question was originally asked by Ailon and Rudnick, but they use $-1$ instead of $+1$ and asked if $\gcd(2^n-1,3^n-1)=1$ for infinitely many $n$. In this setting, for more general $a$ and $b$, the right question/conjecture would be $\gcd(a^n-1,b^n-1)=\gcd(a-1,b-1)$. They prove something stronger if you replace $\mathbb Z$ with $\mathbb C[t]$. Here's the Ailon-Rudnick paper:

N. Ailon and Z. Rudnick, ‘[Torsion points on curves and common divisors of $a^k-1$ and $b^k-1$](https://doi.org/10.4064/aa113-1-3), *Acta Arith*., **113** (2004), no. 1, 31–38 ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2046966)).

There have been lots of articles on this and related problems. For example, a Google search on "Ailon Rudnick gcd" brings up recent articles such as:

- On some extensions of the Ailon–Rudnick theorem, A Ostafe - *Monatshefte für Mathematik*, 2016  ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3539944))
- [On a variant of the Ailon–Rudnick theorem in finite characteristic](http://nyjm.albany.edu:8000/j/2017/23_213.html). D Ghioca, LC Hsia, TJ Tucker - *New York Journal of Mathematics*, 2017 ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3625452))
- [Greatest common divisors of iterates of polynomials](https://doi.org/10.2140/ant.2017.11.1437), LC Hsia, T Tucker - *Algebra & Number Theory*, 2017 ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3687102))